# The +a part of SPF records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

I just want to clarify the +a part of an SPF record since I have an idea how this works but I am unsure.

spf record for example.com

```
v=spf1 +a -all
```

My current understanding is that if there is a valid a record for the server it will be accepted.

For example:

```
A: example.com 123.456.789.12
```

the IP address above would be a valid sender for example.com because of +a.

However I am unsure about sub-domains and how this works.

```
A: server-1.example.com 123.456.789.13
A: server-2.example.com 123.456.789.14
```

Would these IP addresses also be allowed to send as example.com because of the +a part of the SPF record?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like 
   v=spf1 a -all
is the same as
   v=spf1 a:example.com -all. So because of this I would need to add seporate records for server-1.example.com and server-2.example.com?

Comment: please don't use `123.456.789.012` when making up A-records, it is not a possible IP address(456 and 789 > 255) and makes it hard to answer your question with a good example

Comment: Is server-1.example.com truly a subdomain name and not just an A record (host) on example.com?

Comment: It is just an a record for example.com pointing at a different IP address

Answer (score 7):

To give a valid example of how to use the `a`-mechanism with an FQDN other than the current SPF record, here is a few options:

`a` mechanism with a *domain* name as  argument (and how it expands):

```
v=spf1 a:server-1.example.com a:server-2.example.com -all
v=spf1 123.456.789.13         123.456.789.14         -all
```

`a` mechanism with a *CIDR prefix* as argument (and how it expands):

```
v=spf1 a/24              -all
v=spf1 123.456.789.12/24 -all
```

You can either use a *specific FQDN to lookup* (`server-1.example.com`) and then trust the registered IP address(es) for that host, or you can perform a lookup on the *current FQDN* - that is, the domain name for which we are currently performing the SPF check for. You can then add a prefix to specify an entire network segment around the resulting IP address(es).

Both of the above examples will work for you domain, given the details in your question, but I would recommend the first option.

One more thing:

### `a` is the same as `+a`

The `+` qualifier is the default qualifier, no need for that.

Comment: Great post. The + sign confused me between different guides. Also, can "a" be alone to symbolize the current website while using a:someadditionalsite.com  like in "v=spf1 +mx +a +a:someadditionalsite.com -all" ?

Comment: @SILENT absolutely - again, `+` is implied and unnecessary, `v=spf1 mx a a:someadditionalsite.com -all` will suffice

Answer (score 5):

`a` would only include the a record(s) of example.com, unless you explicitely specify a hostname eg.`a:server-1.example.com`. if your servers all have ips in the same subnet you could for example specify `a/24` which would include example.com's A record and all ips in the same /24

see http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#a

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any examples of records that a might cover other than just example.com. As far as I can tell a only covers the a record for example.com.